# Why isn't energy wasted with reversible computing? Isn't information discarded when we feed the function with a new input?

Tags: reversible-computing

I understand that irreversible computing consumes energy because it has to "get rid" of outputs which have been used. With reversible computing that information is not "wasted" because with the outputs we can calculate the inputs again. But what happens after that? Is there a endless loop of back-and-forth calculation input -> output, output -> input? And what happens when we want the gate to calculate the output of some other inputs? Won't it have to discard the previous input/output which leads to the same information/heat dissipation?

Comment: I remember reading an idea for a practical zero-energy implementation of a reversible computer that would bounce back and forth forever. However, an arbitrarily small amount of energy could be used to make it slightly more likely to go forth, than to go back.